# ¿Cómo obtener el titulo que corresponda del vídeo en el foreach?

Tags: php, mysqli

De esta forma almaceno los datos `$data[$type_format][] = $url;` y mediante el uso del `foreach ($data['video'] as $url)` obtengo todas las URL `mp4` del formato `video`.

De la siguiente table:

```
id    title    type_format    url    detail_text
1    title1       video      1.mp4     NULL
1    title2       video      2.mp4     NULL
1    title3       video      3.mp4     NULL
1    title1       text        NULL     detalle1
```

Obteniendo la siguiente impresión:

```
<a class="link" href="1.mp4"></a>
<a class="link" href="2.mp4"></a>
<a class="link" href="3.mp4"></a>
```

Mediante el siguiente código:

```
    $stmt->bind_result($title, $type_format, $url, $detail_text);

    $data = [
      'text'  => [],
      'video' => [],
    ];

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $data[$type_format][] = $url;
    }

    echo '<nav id="enlaces" class="vids">';
    foreach ($data['video'] as $url) {
      echo '<a class="link" href="'.$url.'">'.$title.'</a>';
    }
    echo '</nav>';
```

Ahora mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo enviar más datos al foreach para así imprimir su respectivo titulo de cada enlace?

para obtener el siguiente resultado

```
<a class="link" href="1.mp4">title1</a>
<a class="link" href="2.mp4">title2</a>
<a class="link" href="3.mp4">title3</a>
```

---

Actualización

```
            $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT title,type_format,url,detail_text FROM videos");
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();

            $stmt->bind_result($title, $type_format,$url,$detail_text);

            $i = 1;
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                echo '<nav id="enlaces" class="vids">';
                echo '<a class="link" href="'.$url.'">'.$title.'</a>';
                echo '</nav>';

                echo '<div id="ocultado" style="display: none">';
                echo '<div class="cuadro" id="c_link_'.$i.'" >'.$detail_text.'</div>';
                echo '</div>';

            $i++;

            }
```

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿el código que muestras es tal cual? No entiendo por qué primero guardas en el `while` cada valor en `$data[$type_format][] ` para luego ¿a continuación? sacarlo de nuevo con `foreach ($data['video'] as $url) {` ¿Por qué has concebido el código así. Eso tendría sentido si necesitaras devolver el resultado a otra parte, pero no para usarlo ahí mismo. Estás mareando a los datos, leyéndolos tres veces, guardándolos dos veces y finalmente mostrándolos. ¿?

Comment: @A.Cedano Lo realizo porque necesito mostrar los datos en dos contenedores distintos que no se pueden repetir mediante el uso de `bucle while`

Comment: ¿O sea que más adelante hay otra lecturas más de datos? ¿Ese otro contenedor está en ese mismo archivo? Podrías crear tus dos contenedores **por separado** dentro del `while` **usando variables** y luego mostrarlos donde haga falta.

Comment: @A.Cedano Si todo esos datos están en la misma tabla de datos, por lo tanto debe ir en el mismo archivo de la consulta. NO ENTIENDO, si creo los contenedores dentro del ``while` los contenedores se van a repetir varias veces según el total de registro `<nav></nav><nav></nav><nav></nav><nav></nav>` no doy con lo que me dices :(

Comment: ¿No es eso lo que quieres, mostrar los datos que trae la consulta en dos partes distintas? Los contenedores superiores se pondrían sólo una vez, antes del bucle y al final del bucle. Si necesitas que todas las filas de la consulta queden entre una etiqueta `nav` y otra `div` con parámetros y cosas distintas harías esto: `$mNav="<nav>"; $mDiv="<div>"; while (...){ $mNav.="...dato por fila para el nav... "; $mDiv.=" ... dato por fila para el div..."; } $mNav.="</nav>"; $mDiv.="</div>";` En `$mNav` tendrías tu contenedor `nav` y en `$mDiv` tu `div` para mostrarlos luego. ¿Entiendes o no?

Comment: @A.Cedano No, disculpa que sea ruda, puedes publicar una respuesta por favor, lo que quiero conseguir al final es esto: https://jsfiddle.net/4at3g85c/

Comment: No tengo problema en escribir una respuesta, pero veo que muestras un código a medias y quizá el código se puede optimizar todavía más. Viendo que usas esto: `$stmt->bind_result($title, $type_format, $url, $detail_text);` me gustaría saber de dónde traes los datos y si usas un bucle también para traer cada fila de la base de datos ¿? No entiendo muy bien que hace ese código ahí arriba antes del `while`

Comment: @A.Cedano He actualizado mi pregunta, en el contenedor `<nav id="enlaces" class="vids"></nav>` solo deben ir la URL de videos, la columna `type_format` se basa a dos tipos `text` y `video`, y en el contenedor `<div id="ocultado" style="display: none"></div>` debe ir solo texto, es decir que solo debe tomar en cuenta  el registro en la columna `type_format` de tipos `text`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas:

- leer los datos con el `fetch` para guardarlos (1 bucle `while`)
- leer de nuevo **los mismos datos** guardados con un `for` para crear el `nav`
- leer de nuevo **los mismos datos** con otro `for` para crear el `div`...

Los datos van a terminar mareados y estás derrochando recursos en el servidor.

Mediante este código podrías reproducir exactamente la estructura que muestras en el fiddle de tu comentario:

```
        $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT title,type_format,url,detail_text FROM videos");
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        $stmt->bind_result($title, $type_format,$url,$detail_text);

        $i = 1;
        $mNav="<nav id=\"enlaces\" class=\"vids\">";
        $mDivs="<div id=\"ocultado\" style=\"display: none;\">";
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $mNav.="<a class=\"link\" href=\"$url\">$title</a>";
            $mDivs.="<div class=\"cuadro\" id=\"c_link_$i\">$detail_text</div>";
        $i++;
        }
        $mDivs.="</div>";
        $mNav.="</nav>";

        echo $mNav;
        echo $mDivs;
```

La clave está en abrir y cerrar los contenedores `nav` y `div` antes y después del bucle.

Comment: No me mostraba los resultados, pero faltaba un punto, en las concatenación final `$mDivs.="</div>"; $mNav.="</nav>";` Muchas gracias por el tiempo y la paciencia, no sabes el dolor de cabeza que me has quitado y lo mejor sin que use demasiado recursos el sistema, muchas gracias :)

Comment: @Lou sí, fue un error mío de escritura, lo he corregido en la respuesta. Me alegro de que te haya sido de ayuda. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear un array asociativo asi:

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $data[$type_format][] = Array("url" => $url, "title" => $title);
}

echo '<nav id="enlaces" class="vids">';
foreach ($data['video'] as $url) {
  echo '<a class="link" href="'.$url['url'].'">'.$url['title'].'</a>';
}
echo '</nav>';
```

Comment: No entiendo porque si no estas sobreescribiendo nada.

Comment: Los dos `foreach` son iguales?

Comment: Me refiero al contenido de los `foreach`.  Es el mismo?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91936/discussion-between-alanfcm-and-lou).

Comment: Mil disculpa amigo por el tiempo que te he quitado lastimosamente el uso de los `array, foreach` no está funcionando como quería :( agradezco la paciencia y el tiempo dedicado :)